# How to aggregate after fetching result using groupby using itertools

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-itertools

I am having a list as

```
a=[{'name': 'xyz','inv_name':'asd','quant':300,'amt':20000, 'current':30000},{'name': 'xyz','inv_name':'asd','quant':200,'amt':2000,'current':3000}]
```

This list i have fetched using itertools groupby.

I want to form a list after adding up the quant, amt and current filed for same name and inv_name and create a list something like : `[{'name':'xyz','inv_name':'asd','quant':500,'amt':22000,'current':33000}`

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: you can try annotate queries in django
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: In which way this question is related to `Django` ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge sorry its related to python and its itertool module so Djano removed Django tagging.

Comment: If the below solution solved your problem, please consider accepting (green tick on left), or feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy using a 3rd party library, `pandas` accepts a list of dictionaries:

```
import pandas as pd

a=[{'name': 'xyz','inv_name':'asd','quant':300,'amt':20000, 'current':30000},
   {'name': 'xyz','inv_name':'asd','quant':200,'amt':2000,'current':3000}]

df = pd.DataFrame(a)

res = df.groupby(['name', 'inv_name'], as_index=False).sum().to_dict(orient='records')

# [{'amt': 22000,
#   'current': 33000,
#   'inv_name': 'asd',
#   'name': 'xyz',
#   'quant': 500}]
```